# ACF fields are disappear after deployed code from local to development or staging server ( Using Deployer Script )

Tags: field, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I am facing the issue, when I deployed the code from local to development server or staging server ACF fields are disappeared on the pages, if I do save the specific field group here [ACF Group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2A1V7.png) then the ACF fields are showing on the page [ACF Field Showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3dKA.png) but that is annoying so I updated the latest ACF Pro version "5.9.0" but still happening so I don't understand why that is happening.

I have also checked ACF json folder permission is the same 755 as per the ACF documentation and synchronization fields are working properly but without saving the fields are not showing in the page.

So if anyone facing same issue and have any solution please share in comment.